# SSRS Target Line

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to re-create a line chart in SSRS like the one below (created in excel)

Target vs Revenue

[image]

I can re-create the running value (green line - revenue) but I have no idea how to do the straight target line (grey one) that should end at the end of the current month. The value for this line comes from a text parameter (I type in the target for current month manually), so ideally this should be a running value of the parameter number divided by the number of days for this month ending on the last day.

Can I have an angled StripLine to achieve that or shall I use an expression, if so, can you help me to build it, please?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you know what month you are running the report for and you can therefore determine the number of days in that month. I won;t cover that here, ask a new question if you can't do that.

To create your target line, open your dataset properties, click the 'Fields' tab and Add a new field.

Call the new field Target or whatever you want and hit the `fx` button next to field source. Set the field source to following expression.

```
=(Parameters!Target.Value/31) * DAY(Fields!myRevenueDateField.Value)
```

You will just need to swap out the 31 for the actual number of days in the month, and the correct date fields from your dataset.

I used some sample data in my test with a target of 3000 and got the following result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help and clear explanation Alan, it works.